# Mail preview wrong after setting HTMLBody

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, mailitem

I am developing a vsto add-in for Outlook.

I am trying to set the `HTMLBody` of the mail. However, if the mail I open is present in `Drafts` folder, I can set the `HTMLBody` of the mail and the preview shown is fine. But if the mail is present in the `Deleted Items` folder,  the `HTMLBody` property of the mail is set but the preview just doesn't show the updated content. Is there any way to refresh the preview? Or am I missing something?

**Update 1:**

I have a **separate** form region, for the mail item.
I have a draft on which I am working. Lets say, it's initial HTML content is **A**. Lets say, I am setting the `HTMLBody` property of the mail to **B**, after navigating to the form region. But I am not yet saving the mail. So when I navigate back to the mailbody, I can see the changes (mail body displays **B**) for the time being. Of course the changes will be lost if i don't save.

But, now I delete the draft, so that it moves to Deleted Items folder. The HTML content is still **A** as it was not saved.. Now when I open this draft (from deleted items folder), and navigate to form, I set the HTMLBody property to **B**. But it doesn't show that change when I navigate back to the mail body. The mail body still shows **A**.(The inspector is still open, it's not closed) But when I check in my debugger, the HTMLBody property is set to B. Why?

Comment: Do you save the message?

Comment: No. I don't save the message. But the same thing is working if the mail item is in Drafts!

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko If I attach the debugger, I can see that the HTMLBody property is set. But it doesn't show in the mail body! Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the message (`MailItem.Save`), otherwise the changes are mot persisted. If the messages is moved to the Deleted Items folder, it is a physically different message, and it will not carry over any unsaved changes.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Can you please check?

Comment: One way or another, you need to save the messages to see the changes. If you don't, all bets are off.

Comment: Yes, If I want those changes to be seen the next time I open the mail, I would have to save the mail. But I just have my inspector open in edit mode. And I set the HTMLBody property. Shouldn't that be visible in the inspector at that instant? The same works if the item is from drafts folder. Why? Am I still missing something?

Comment: Using Inspector.WordEditor to make changes while the items is still being displayed might be a better idea.

Comment: I was able to debug my issue. The problem was that, when my mail was moved from draft to deleted items, the add-in was still referring to the older mailitem object, which was in draft. Thus it was never updated with my changes.
One important thing I learnt is that when using formregions, always refer to currentItem using `this.OutlookItem`